# How to execute a DDL from c?

Tags: sql, c, oracle, ddl

All,

I want to execute `a DDL`(Data Definition Language) `from C code`.

What are the alternatives to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use [dynamic ESQL with PRO*C](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14407/pc_13dyn.htm#i13162):

```
EXEC SQL EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
     "CREATE TABLE dyn1 (col1 VARCHAR2(4))";
```

Another option is to use `system` to run SQL*Plus.
On a Linux type system it could look something like this:

```
<write sql command(s) to sql file>
system("cat mycommands.sql | sqlplus dbuser/password@myDatabase");
```

or this:

```
system("echo 'drop table myTable' | sqlplus dbuser/password@myDatabase");
```

If you are already using PRO*C I would recommend the PRO*C approach, because it gives much better control over error handling.